# Xamarin.FilePicker returns null FileData objects

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, filepicker

I am trying to implement the package "FilePicker" on xamarin.Forms, but unfortunately without success.

Here's the code in XAML.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.FilePicker;
using Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions;

namespace FilesTest
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    async void Pic()
    {
        try
        {
            FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            if (fileData == null) {
                Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                return; // user canceled file picking
            }
            string fileName = fileData.FileName;
            string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

            System.Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void PickFileButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pic();
    }
}
}
```

**edit**: For those who asked, I am trying to make it work on android, and my AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.FilesTest">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<application android:label="FilesTest.Android"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

(the code in XAML is just a simple button that calls the PickFileButton_Clicked() method when it is being clicked)

After hours of debugging, nothing else is being written on my console other than those '~' characters... I understand that the FileData object is null after file picking (and no, the file that's being picked is a simple text file...), but I just could not find any information on why it may happen. Does anyone knows why the FileData object is null? please help.

Comment: have you followed the steps in the docs in the section marked IMPORTANT?

Comment: @Jason Might help if you link to those docs...

Comment: https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows#important

Comment: Is this with Android or iOS? Have you set up permissions and permission requests? If Android, what does Logcat say or if iOS what does the console say? If this is a .netstandard project, In the Android or iOS projects, have you also added the File Picker nuget package? In short, there are a whole bunch of reasons this may not be working, we need more information.

Comment: @Jason If you mean that the problem it with the permissions, I've edited the question and added my AndroidManifest.xml file, so you can see the permissions. Although I'm not sure that I'm doing it right...

Comment: @CurtisShipley It's with Android. I set up permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file. As for the Logcat - it doesn't say much apart from "mono-stdout" and then a bunch of '~'s, which means that the FileData object is null... What would you wish to know specifically on the Logcat?

Comment: @OriBarmatz Logcat (not the debug output from Visual Studio), will sometimes give you other information about what is happening. What version of Android is this. Android 7+ wants you to request permissions. Is this with a shared project, or .net standard project?

Comment: @CurtisShipley I run It on an Android 8.1, and it is a shared project. Logcat says: failed to get memory consumption info: -1, Couldn't load memtrack module, and also DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').

Comment: With Android 8, you also have to request the user's permission. Just putting it in the manifest is not enough. You're looking for something more meaningful in the logcat, likely outputted right after that call is made.

Answer (score 2):

**It works, thank all the supporters!**

The problem:
**permissions.**

After digging deep and learning how to handle permissions with android and Xamarin, I managed to read a text file from the phone's memory.

In addition, I switched from Xam.Plugin.FilePicker, which had more downloads on the Xamarin Nuget manager, to Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker. Idk exactly if it helped tho.

**Final code:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.FilePicker;
using Plugin.FilePicker.Abstractions;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace FilesTest
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
{
    public IntPtr Handle => default(IntPtr) ;

    public MainPage(){InitializeComponent();}

    async void Pic()//the function that triggers the file picker
    {
        try
        {
            FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            if (fileData == null) {
                return; // user canceled file picking
            }
            string fileName = fileData.FileName;
            string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

            Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void PickFileButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)//in the xaml there is a button that triggers this function
    {
        var thisActivity = Forms.Context as Activity;
        if(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != Permission.Granted)
        {// Permission is not granted
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[] {Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);//1 is just the code to retrive this permission
        } else
        {//if permission is already granted
            Pic();
        }
    }

    public void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults) // this function is called after the permission box is shown and the user picked whether to grant or deny the permission
    {
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {
            if(grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {//permission has been granted by the user
                Pic();
            } else
            {//permission denied
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose(){}
}
}
```

Comment: I was facing the issue that after selecting the file, the code was not going to next statement after FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(); may be due to some internal error, but I was not able to get any exception. I have just replaced Xam.Plugin.FilePicker with Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker and it has started to work. Thanks for mentioning it.